# Put DN into variable VBS

Tags: vbscript

I am creating a script that will allow me to enter a username in our domain, and have it look up attributes from their AD profile.

So first I am getting the users' DN. Once I have that - I can run;

```
Set objAD = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & ***I NEED DN HERE***)
```

and query specific attributes to be output.

So what I need to do is somehow get the DN into a variable to put into the LDAP query. I know (I think) I need to get it from the Do Loop below, but am having a complete blank and can't figure out how to just put the whole DN into a variable.

```
Username = InputBox("Enter UserName to lookup...")  

Set rootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
base = "<LDAP://" & rootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext") & ">"

fltr = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=Person)" & "(sAMAccountName=" & UserName & "))"

attr = "distinguishedName,sAMAccountName"
scope = "subtree"

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
conn.Open "Active Directory Provider"

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandText = base & ";" & fltr & ";" & attr & ";" & scope

Set rs = cmd.Execute
Do Until rs.EOF
  WScript.Echo rs.Fields("distinguishedName").Value
  rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close

conn.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has the same problem - it was an easy fix.
Just needed to write it to a variable instead of echoing.

```
Do Until rs.EOF
  strDN = rs.Fields("distinguishedname").value
  rs.MoveNext
Loop
```